# Laravel - Test run in terminal - OK vs Test run in - Run ...test... with Coverage in PhpStorm - Error

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

Test run by typing `phpunit` in PhpStorm's Terminal.

[image]

All OK.

---

The same test run by right click on it and `Run this test with Coverage`.

[image]

[image]

Error! :<

---

run PhpStorm's auto conf I didn't set anything

[image]

Comment: You're using two different versions of `phpunit/phpunit`.

Comment: @localheinz is there a way to upgare phpstorms phpunit?

Comment: Is `phpunit/phpunit` a (development) dependency of your project? If so you should probably run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` (or whatever the equivalent of that is on a Windows machine) instead of `phpunit`. The former will run the version of `phpunit/phpunit` as installed with `composer`, the latter the globally installed version. That may not solve your problem, but it might be a step into the right direction.

Comment: *"is there a way to upgare phpstorms phpunit"* PhpStorm does not have own PHPUnit -- it uses version whatever you point to. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications

Comment: @LazyOne is correct. Check File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks or .. | PHPUnit if you use 2017.1 or below.

Comment: Are you sure that it's actually the coverage? The screenshot looks like you get a 500 error response, suggesting you have an issue in your code. I suggest removing old test-logs, run the tests again and check the logs for any (fatal) errors and exceptions.

Comment: May you share the error?